# How to refresh chromium (F5) from shell script in debian (alternative of xdotool)

Tags: raspbian, ssh, debian, chrome

I need to find an alternative to `xdotool`. I am using a Raspberry Pi to refresh a webpage regularly using chromium. For this, I use a shell script:

```
xdotool search --name chromium key --clearmodifiers ${RELOAD}
```

However, `xdotool` makes my system too busy, until it eventually stops responding. Would there be any alternative to `xdotool` that wouldn't be so heavy on my system?

**Edit (complete shell script)**

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
RELOAD="CTRL+R"
while (true)
do
    wget -q --spider http://google.com
    if [ $? == $a ]; then
        ps cax | grep chromium
        if [ $? == $a ]; then
            echo "chrome running"
        else    
            echo "chrome starting"
            /home/pi/Desktop/APPLICATION_CALENDAR.SH &          
        fi
        echo $? $a
        echo "online1"
        xdotool search --name chromium key --clearmodifiers ${RELOAD}
    else
        echo "offline"
        sleep 15s
    fi
sleep 20s   
done
```

Comment: What is wrong with calling xdotool less often?  How are you calling the script at the moment?

Comment: I am doing refresh after 20 secs, 
My shell script code is as above in the Question now.

it slows down the raspberry pi too much

Comment: Running a complete graphical interface with all chromium dependencies (and maybe some GNOME?) slows down the Raspberry Pi... It's a matter of perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Visiting a webpage does not require a full graphical interface with a browser: all it takes is an HTTP request. Using cURL and Cron, you should be able to schedule an HTTP request every n minutes, for instance.

For instance, the following `cron` call accesses `example.com`:

```
curl http://example.com
```

If you have a look at your output, you'll see the HTML source code of your website. Now, if you want to do this, let's say, every minute, you could use...

```
watch -n60 curl http://example.com
```

... which will *watch* the output of `curl` every 60 seconds.

If you want all of this to happen in the background, you may want to schedule a cron job. Run `crontab -e` to edit your user's crontab, and enter your job:

```
5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://example.com > /dev/null 2>&1
```

[For more information about cron job scheduling, have a look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Now, while `curl` usually performs a *GET* request, you might want to add some *POST* information to your request (forms). *POST* data can be added using the `--data` switch:

```
curl --data='username=myuser&myemail=myemail@provider.tld' http://example.com
```

If you want to add parameters to a *GET* request instead, just add them in the URL, just like they appear in your browser.

Another interesting point about cURL : cookie jars. These allow you to maintain a session across several cURL requests. For instance, if you make a login request...

```
curl -c ~/cookiejar --data='login=mylog&pass=mypass' http://example.com/login.php
```

... the `-c` switch will store your session's data into `~/cookiejar`. Now, if you want to visit your private profile...

```
curl -c ~/cookiejar http://example.com/private.php
```

... you'll be able to access it since your cookie information will have been passed along with the request.

Finally, I would suggest you use SSL whenever you pass credentials over HTTP. Here is a typical login example:

```
$ curl -c ~/cookiejar --data='login=mylogin&pass=mypass' https://example.com/login.php
$ curl -c ~/cookiejar https://example.com/private.php
$ curl -c ~/cookiejar https://example.com/logout.php
$ rm ~/cookiejar
```

... or, for the more paranoid: `shred -fuvz -n3 ~/cookiejar`.

Note that cURL is available as a library is a variety of language, such as [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), [C](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/), [Python](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/), and so on...